# Base internationalization and other localizations, set default language?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to localize my application in English and Italian. If the device is configured with another language, I want to show the English version.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

In the .plist file:
[image]

And the storyboard:

[image]

The problem is that when I set on my device another language (i.e. French or Spanish), the showed version is the last one showed among Italian and English.

I.e. I set my phone in Italian, everything works fine, then I change in Spanish, and the app is in Italian again. I set my phone in English, everything works fine, then I change in Spanish, and the app is in English again.

How can I solve having English for every non-localized languages?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is wrong. If the user prefers Italian to English, but prefers French to both, your UI should obviously be in Italian.